# Variable not showing up after submit

Tags: php

I am fairly new to php and I have a form which when filled out sends ?sent which is checked for in an if statement. My problem is that after the form is submitted the .ucfirst( $firstName ). ' ' .ucfirst( $lastName ) never show up when echod in

```
echo '<h2>Thank you, ' .ucfirst( $firstName ). ' ' .ucfirst( $lastName ). ' for your submission, we will be contacting you shortly if needed.</h2>';
```

Here is the full code:

```
<?php
$firstName   = $_POST[ 'firstName' ];
$lastName       = $_POST[ 'lastName' ];
$email          = $_POST[ 'email' ];
$comments  = $_POST[ 'comments' ];
$errors         = array();

if (isset($_GET['sent']) === true) {

    echo '<h2>Thank you, ' .ucfirst( $firstName ). ' ' .ucfirst( $lastName ). ' for your submission, we will be contacting you shortly if needed.</h2>'; 

} else {                                                                     ////////////////////////////////////// else ////////////////////////////////////////////////////

?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="firstName"  placeholder="first name" <?php if(isset($_POST['firstName']) === true ){ echo 'value="' .strip_tags($_POST['firstName']). '"' ;} ?>/><br />
    <input type="text" name="lastName"  placeholder="last name" <?php if(isset($_POST['lastName']) === true ){ echo 'value="' .strip_tags($_POST['lastName']). '"' ;} ?>/><br />
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email address" <?php if(isset($_POST['email']) === true ){ echo 'value="' .strip_tags($_POST['email']). '"' ;} ?>/><br />
    <textarea name="comments" id="comments" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="comments...."><?php if(isset($_POST['comments']) === true ){  echo strip_tags($_POST['comments'])  ;} ?></textarea><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" /><br />
    <?php foreach($errors as $error) {
        echo $error;
    } 

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    if ( empty($_POST['lastName']) && empty($_POST['firstName']) && empty($_POST['email']) && empty($_POST['comments']) ) {
        $errors[] = '&bull; All fields are required for form to be submitted!<br />';
    } else {
        if (ctype_alpha($_POST['firstName']) === false ) {
            $errors[] = '&bull; First name must contain only letters!<br />';
        }
        if (ctype_alpha($_POST['lastName']) === false ) {
            $errors[] = '&bull; Last name must contain only letters!<br />';
        }

        if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
            $errors[] = '&bull; You must enter a valid email address!<br />';
        }
        if (empty($_POST['comments']) === true ) {
            $errors[] = '&bull; Tell us why you would like to contact us!<br />';
        }
    }
    if (empty($errors)) {
        header('Location: testForm.php?sent');
        end();
    }


}                                                                               ///////////////////////////////////// end submit ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
}                                                                               ///////////////////////////////////// end else //////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
?>
</form>
```

Comment: You have an XSS vulnerability.

Comment: Change this `if (isset($_GET['sent']) === true) {` to `if (isset($_POST['sent']) === true) {` then try again. GET and POST are two different animals.

Comment: @Fred-ii- : look at this line : `header('Location: testForm.php?sent');`

Comment: @Brewal What about it? The OP is mixing GET and POST, won't work for one thing.

Comment: `$_POST['sent']` does not exists in his code

Comment: @Fred-ii- why wouldn't mixing GET & POST work?

Comment: @Brewal It is quite confusing, I must say. I'm not touching this one.

Comment: @MLeFevre For one thing, it's obvious that's it's POST type of form and I see not mention of GET anywhere else. Although as `Brewal` already stated about `header('Location: testForm.php?sent');` and that `$_POST['sent'] does not exists in his code` is the most probable cause for a fail. Again, I'm not touching this one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You redirect the user using `header()`, but in this step, you are of course loosing the previously POSTed-data (lines 3-5), thats why first name and last name must be empty.

As a solution, try filling the error-variables in the start of the script. This way, you can check if `$errors` is empty directly in line 7 instead of using the redirect stuff.

If you want to use the **redirect-aber-post-pattern**, you will have to include the two needed parameters for the output into the header-redirect. That way, your solution could be:

```
// use this replace against header injection if you got php-version < 4.4.2 or < 5.1.2
// - or update your php-version
$hlastname = str_replace("\n", $_POST['lastName'], ""); 
$hfirstname = str_replace("\n", $_POST['firstName'], "");
header('Location: testForm.php?sent=true&firstName='.$hfirstname.'&lastName='.$hlastname);

// and put this into your fist lines:

$firstname = htmlentities($_REQUEST['firstName']);
$lastname = htmlentities($_REQUEST['lastName']);
```

In addition, **your script is not safe**. You have to escape your parameters against xss attacks! Please read more about XSS-vulnerabilities before continuing to program a PHP-application (Google will help you!; compare with my usage of htmlentities()).

Comment: I am checking out xss - vulnerabilities right now. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

You only echo that statement out if $_GET['sent'] === true;.

However, you are sending a POST request.  Try this:

```
if (isset($_POST['firstName']) {
//echo code here
}
```

Comment: He is actually doing a redirect at the end of his code to prevent the form to be submited again : `header('Location: testForm.php?sent');`

Answer (score 0):

For what you want to do it is not needed to redirect the page with another GET request that does the same again.

Just validate your data at the top of the page, like this:

```
<?php
$firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
$lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];
$errors = array();


if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if (empty($_POST['lastName']) && empty($_POST['firstName']) && empty($_POST['email']) && empty($_POST['comments'])) {
    $errors[] = '&bull; All fields are required for form to be submitted!<br />';
} else {
    if (ctype_alpha($_POST['firstName']) === false) {
        $errors[] = '&bull; First name must contain only letters!<br />';
    }
    if (ctype_alpha($_POST['lastName']) === false) {
        $errors[] = '&bull; Last name must contain only letters!<br />';
    }

    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
        $errors[] = '&bull; You must enter a valid email address!<br />';
    }
    if (empty($_POST['comments']) === true) {
        $errors[] = '&bull; Tell us why you would like to contact us!<br />';
    }
}
if (count($errors)==0) { // if no errors
    echo '<h2>Thank you, ' . ucfirst($firstName) . ' ' . ucfirst($lastName) . ' for your submission, we will be contacting you shortly if needed.</h2>';
} else { // ese show form with errors

?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="first name" <?php if (isset($_POST['firstName']) === true) {
        echo 'value="' . strip_tags($_POST['firstName']) . '"';
    } ?>/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="last name" <?php if (isset($_POST['lastName']) === true) {
        echo 'value="' . strip_tags($_POST['lastName']) . '"';
    } ?>/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email address" <?php if (isset($_POST['email']) === true) {
        echo 'value="' . strip_tags($_POST['email']) . '"';
    } ?>/><br/>
    <textarea name="comments" id="comments" cols="30" rows="10"
              placeholder="comments...."><?php if (isset($_POST['comments']) === true) {
            echo strip_tags($_POST['comments']);
        } ?></textarea><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit"/><br/>
    <?php foreach ($errors as $error) {
        echo $error;
    }
    }
    }
    ?>
</form>
```